# Regex for ranges of values in comma-separated list

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that match a list of numeric values, given in a comma-separated list, ranges allowed. Empty is not allowed.

Something like: 1-10,20-56,8,7

So far I have (([0-9]+)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+),)*[0-9]+. This does most of the job, except it misses the case of one range only (eg: 1-10 would not validate).

The checking for each range can be omitted (eg: 20-10 can be allowed as a valid range).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the regex;

```
^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)(,([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?))*$
```

[**Regex in action**](http://www.ideone.com/GNR2b)

Comment: my version : ^([0-9]+)(-[0-9]+)*(,([0-9]+)(-[0-9]+)*)*$. It's more or less the same :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is one (number or range) optionally followed by zero or more:  comma plus (number or range):

```
(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,(?:\d+(-\d+)?))*
```

This uses the `\d` shortcut for [0-9] and the `(?: ... )` non-capturing parentheses construct.

This regex doesn't allow any spaces to be included in the list.  To allow those, insert the "optional space" `\s*` between each term:

```
\s*(?:\d+(\s*-\s*\d+)?)\s*(?:,\s*(?:\d+(\s*-\s*\d+)?)\s*)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that CORE of your patter is

```
([0-9]+.)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

It matches a single numeric value or a range. So, what you need is:

```
(CORE,)*CORE
```

And what you have is:

```
(CORE,)*DIGIT
```

Do like this and you will be fine:

```
(([0-9]+.)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+),)*([0-9]+.)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were looking for is:

```
(CORE)(,\s+CORE)*
```

This will allow lists that are:

CORE
CORE, CORE
CORE,  CORE
CORE,  CORE, CORE

and so on.

Hope this helps,
David