# Regex parse a list of comma separated number ranges, and capture them in individual groups

Tags: regex, scala

I found [the following regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310439/regex-for-ranges-of-values-in-comma-separated-list#4310530) for matching comma separated numbers or ranges of numbers:

```
val reg = """^(\d+(-\d+)?)(,\s*(\d+(-\d+)?))*$""".r
```

While this *does match* valid strings, I only get *one String* out of it, instead of *a list of strings*, each corresponding to one of the separated entries. E.g.

```
reg.findAllIn("1-2, 3").map(s => s""""$s"""").toList
```

Gives

```
List("1-2, 3")
```

But I want:

```
List("1-2", "3")
```

---

The following comes closer:

```
val list = "1-2, 3" match {
  case Reg(groups @ _*) => groups
  case _ => Nil
}

list.map(s => s""""$s"""")
```

But it contains all sorts of 'garbage':

```
List("1-2", "-2", ", 3", "3", "null")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `findAllIn` you should not try to match the entire string. It will split by the biggest continuos match it can find. Instead what you need is just a part of your regex:

```
val reg = """(\d+(-\d+)?)""".r
```

If you use this with `findAllIn` it will return what you need.

```
scala> val x = """(\d+(-\d+)?)""".r
x: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+(-\d+)?)

scala> x.findAllIn("1-2, 3").toList
res0: List[String] = List(1-2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one step ahead. But now it just swallows everything that it doesn't understand, e.g. `"1-2, schoko 3"` produces the same result, but should be rejected.

Comment: So in this case you want to reject the entire string or skip this part and move on?

Comment: I want to reject the entire string... but... I'm using this with a `JFormattedTextField`, and with the `COMMIT_OR_REVERT` policy, it automatically throws away the garbage, so I think I kind of like that behaviour. (I'm still curious how one can write the matcher to refuse ill formatted strings).

Comment: in that case you can do this in two steps. first validate full string match using the original regex you posted and then extract using what I suggested.